# upload data to server from javascript to php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, multidimensional-array, web-sql

I need to upload websql table to the server using ajax.
when I use indexed array or simple variable code works fine.
I cant figure out what problem is? plz help me.
thanks in advance...
here is javascript:

```
function upload()
{

var db = cropsap.webdb.db;

 db.transaction(function (tx) {

                tx.executeSql('SELECT * from survey', [],function(tx, results) {
                    var data = "";
                    var survey=[];
                    for(var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                        var row = results.rows.item(i); 
                        var result = [];


                        for(var key in row) 
                        {         
                            result[key] = row[key];  
                        }     
                        survey.push(result);
                    }
                    //alert(survey[0]['srno']);//here i get output

               var url = "";
                url = document.getElementById("url").value;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    async: true,

                    data: { "data": JSON.stringify(survey) },
                    error: function () { alert("error occured");},
                    success: function (data) {

                        alert("sucess");
                        alert(data);

                    }
                });
            });
        });
}
```

**php code:**

```
<?php
$survey= json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

        $len = sizeof($crop_insect_survey_details);
        print(" len: ".$len);

            for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
        {
            $srno = $crop_insect_survey_details[$i]['srno'];//here cant get output
            $name = $crop_insect_survey_details[$i]['name'];
            print("srno:".$srno);
            print("name:".$name);
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: php code:<?php
$survey= json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
  
  $len = sizeof($crop_insect_survey_details);
  print(" len: ".$len);
     
   for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
  {
   $srno = $crop_insect_survey_details[$i]['srno'];
   $name = $crop_insect_survey_details[$i]['name'];
   print("srno:".$srno);
   print("name:".$name);
  }

 ?>

Comment: You have the option to edit your question...

Comment: Could you `echo/var_dump $_POST['data']` ?

Comment: I changed  var result = []; to var result = {}; now i can echo 'data' but in php file $len value giving wrong

Comment: `Object` doe not have `.length` property! You must have `[]`

Comment: then it echo blank array with len 1

Comment: Blank array can not have `length` 1

Comment: Check what data is being transmitted over network... Use `Developers tools!`

Comment: I got reason of my problem there is one field in database which holds date and time .when I skip that field code works fine but I need that field also

Comment: Do you send that value from `ajax` ?

Comment: yes i need to save it to server

Comment: Can you share `data` object being sent ? Also share the `schema` of your database!

Comment: here is my create table query CREATE TABLE if not exists survey( srno integer primary key autoincrement,   survey_code bigint NOT NULL,    cir_code integer NOT NULL, ins_code integer NOT NULL,     updatedby bigint NOT NULL,  updateddatetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL)///updateddatetime gives problem

Comment: Set `updateddatetime` as `datetime`

Comment: I set as datetime but still facing same problem. actually it takes date but not taking time

Comment: Just keep it `varchar` and test!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `data: { "data": JSON.stringify(survey) },` You can pass your data inside data key itself.

```
data:JSON.stringify(survey)
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Comment: it prints "error occured" message, what changes i have to do in php code?

Comment: where it's printing "error occured" in js file or php? You can user php php://input to receive data at php file.

Comment: file_get_contents("php://input"), use this syntax it will help you.

Comment: after including file_get_contents("php://input") still it gives same message.it calls error function declared in ajax

Comment: You can see in the console what is actual error there and can print the error in comsole see this for debugging http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758922/how-to-post-data-to-php-file-using-ajax/36759072#36759072

Comment: I used error: function (xhr, status, error) { alert(error); }..it gives alert like-- syntaxError:Unexpected token l

Comment: It happens sometimes for malformed json, try the same request after removing contentType from ajax request.